# What is the difference between (these four) sleep states?

Tags: sleep, standby

Whilst browsing the internet I found an article [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100127122316/http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/windows-7-power-efficiency-report/) about how to run a Power Efficiency Report. As I wasn't doing anything, I decided to try it and see what it did.

In the results it listed the following four sleep states with true of false next to them showing if my PC supports it.

- S1
- S2
- S3
- S4

What are the differences between these sleep states?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I upvoted both answers, Wil got accepted answer because he set out the answer rather than just copy+paste.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**S0 - On / Working**

The computer is powered up. If supported, power conservation is handled
by each device.

**S1 - Sleep**

CPU is stopped. RAM maintains power. Everything else is off, or in low
power mode.

**S2 - Sleep**

CPU has no power. RAM maintains power. Everything else is off, or in
low power mode.

**S3 - Standby**

CPU has no power. RAM maintains power, refreshes slowly. Power supply
reduces power. This level might be referred to as “Save to RAM.” Windows
enters this level when in standby.

**S4 - Hibernate**

Power to most hardware is shut off. Any files in memory are saved to
the hard disk in a temporary file. If configured, the NIC will remain
on for WOL, or AoL. This level is also known as “Save to disk.”

**S5 - Off**

Everything is off. No files are saved. If configured, the NIC will maintain
power to listen for WOL (Magic) packets. This is known as a shutdown.

[Source](http://www.365discoveries.com/2009/01/computer-sleep-states-on-sleep-standby-hibernate-off/)

Comment: How can I know to which of them my computer is configured when sleep ?

Comment: "Sleep" will normally be S3. Some motherboards have an option to let you specify S1 or S3. S2 was rarely implemented.

Comment: It's almost certainly S3. Some systems have an option in the BIOS settings to use S1 instead of S3 for standby - this is for cases where your system won't resume properly from S3.

Comment: how does modern S0ix fit into these?

Comment: I believe modern standby (S0) remains internet-connected while in sleep so the CPU still runs but maintains low power. A lot of newer computers have S0 as set as default but I think they can still be switched between S0 and S3 in the BIOS or through some hidden bootloader.

Comment: S0 is operating. S5 is soft off. The difference between S4 and S5 is just that the software loads session context when waking from S4 and starts fresh when waking from S5. The S4 and S5 hardware power state is the same. It should also be noted that individual systems may have more states, or use G or C rather than S, C is often used with focus on the CPU(intel has both C4 and deeper-C4). G0=S0 is on and operating; G1 is sleep retaining session context; G2 is off, no context saved; S1-S4 are subcategories of G1, S5 is a subcategory of G2. (There could be an S6 but is not standard terminology.)

Answer (score 18):

Excerpt from Wikipedias article on ACPI

> - S0/Working   System is on. The CPU is fully up and running; power conservation is on a per-device basis.
> - S1 Sleep System appears off. The CPU is stopped; RAM is refreshed; the system is running in a low power mode.
> - S2 Sleep System appears off. The CPU has no power; RAM is refreshed; the system is in a lower power mode than S1.
> - S3 Sleep (Standby)   System appears off. The CPU has no power; RAM is in slow refresh; the power supply is in a reduced power mode. This mode is also referred to as 'Save To RAM'.
> - S4 Hibernate System appears off. The hardware is completely off, but system memory has been saved as a temporary file onto the harddisk. This mode is also referred to as 'Save To Disk'.
> - S5/Off   System is off. The hardware is completely off, the operating system has shut down; nothing has been saved. Requires a complete reboot to return to the Working state.

[Here's the full article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)

Comment: I always called S3 "sayonara mode" on Windows XP because it was doubtful that the system would ever get back to S0 and work 100%. Thanks for quoting Wikipedia and saying that. +1

Comment: Just one nit: Hardware is not "completely off" in S4, but power consumption should be the same as in S5. In ALL S-states (even S5) the power supply will maintain +5SB to the motherboard and, sometimes, to a few other peripherals. This permits "wake on LAN", among other things, to work. In fact, even responding to the front panel power button requires +5SB! It normally provides an amp or two at 5 volts. 

The only way to turn off +5SB is to either turn off the PSU with a hard power switch (some have one on the back panel) or else unplug it.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states refers to the "completely off" as "G3"

Comment: S0ix seems to have been added since... "Low power idle" in Windows, "Modern Standby" also seems to be used on the ACPI Wikipedia article