# Execute blocking script with admin rights in Windows before and after standby

Tags: windows, script, crash, sleep, standby

I would like to run a script in Windows right before standby/sleep mode with admin rights and blocking, i.e., the system should not go to sleep until the script has successfully terminated.

Alternatively, it would be possible for me to create a background process or service if it can be done in a simple manner.

Background: It seems I have a very buggy driver for a device which leaves Windows hanging with a blank screen when going to standby or presents a blank screen upon wakeup. This is not 100% reproduceable, it happens only sometimes. However, it seems when I just disable the corresponding device in the device manager, everything works fine. I would like to automate this process.

Answer (score 2):

#### I would like to run a script in Windows right before standby/sleep mode

You can use the Task Scheduler to create a task that is triggered by a Kernel-Power log event that indicates "Sleep":

1. Run "Task Scheduler".
2. Select "Task Scheduler Library
3. Click menu "Action" > "Create Task"
4. Select "General" and give the task a "Name" and Description"
5. Select "Triggers" and click "New"

   - Set "Begin the Task" to "On an Event"
   - Set "Log" to "System"
   - Set "Source" to "Kernel-Power"
   - Set "Event ID" to "42" (Sleep)
   - Click "Ok"

   [image]
6. Select "Actions" and click "New"

   - Set "Program/script" to a script of your choice
   - Click "Ok"

   [image]

---

#### When I disable the corresponding device in the device manager everything works

> I would like to automate this process.

Use `devcon` to disable the device.

Notes:

- Use `devcon find` to get the device hardware ID.
- Use `devcon disable HardwareID` to disable the device.
- Add `devcon disable HardwareID` to the script created above.
- On Windows 7 64 bit you need to use the 32 bit version of `devcon`, as the 64 bit version gives the following error:

  > This version of F:\test\devcon\ia64\devcon.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-
  >   bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
- The download link mentioned below is a zip file containing both 32 and 64 bit versions of devcon.

---

#### Where do I download devcon?

Go to the http://support.microsoft.com page [The DevCon command-line utility functions as an alternative to Device Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311272) for the download link.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [devcon](http://ss64.com/nt/devcon.html) - Device Manager.

Comment: Thanks, great pointer but this only works for **shutdown**. I would need it for **standby** and **sleep** mode.

Comment: @divB Answer updated to use Task Scheduler to run a script on the appropriate Kernel-Power event (EventID 42 is Sleep).

Comment: @divb Note standby and mode are the same thing. See [What is the difference between Sleep and Standby modes?](http://superuser.com/q/367842)

Comment: This works now for standby which is great but it is **not** blocking: For a test, I just let execute calc.exe. When I switch to standby, calc.exe pops up potentially long after I resumed again! Since the buggy driver leaves the system hanging when it goes to standby, I need to disable it **before** it actually goes into standby.