# Difference b/w Hibernation and sleep?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, power

Can Somebody  please tell me the difference b/w Hibernation and sleep?And also why sleep is not available on Ubuntu and only Hibernation is available.?

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/367842/what-is-the-difference-between-sleep-and-standby-modes and probably several others. Please do a little bit of research before asking a question. If you have a specific problem (e.g., “Why can't I activate sleep mode in my Ubuntu?”) please modify your question and add more details about what OS and hardware you are using.

Comment: Ok from the next time I'll search before asking any question.

Answer (score 0):

In sleep mode:

- The computer still uses power, albeit a small amount. This power is used to maintain the data in the RAM. Loss of this power means the loss of the sleep mode and all open documents and data.
- The computer can come back to full working condition in an instant.

In hibernation mode:

- The computer consumes no power whatsoever. It is safe to remove any and all sources of power from a hibernating computer. It can come back to full working condition if and when the power is restored.
- The computer takes some times to resume full working condition. (Definitely more than sleep state.) Data must be read from hard disk drives and put back into RAM.

Ubuntu does support both modes. Maybe your computer does not support one of them. Usually, it is a driver issue.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer , actually I didn't knew this before and my laptop is in sleep mode since a month and still it is in my bag in sleep mode.