# Find out what standby/sleep mode I'm under when on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bios, sleep, standby

How can I find out which [standby/sleep mode](https://superuser.com/questions/71835/what-is-the-difference-between-these-four-sleep-states) I'm under (S1, S2 or S3) when on Windows 7? My BIOS does not have such a setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command prompt run:

```
powercfg -availablesleepstates
```

Short version:

```
powercfg -a
```

> ```
>   -AVAILABLESLEEPSTATES, -A
>               Reports the sleep states available on the system
>               Attempts to report reasons why sleep states are unavailable.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

S2 never really existed.  S1 was a basically useless state that didn't really save any power but did not require added hardware to support.  You can tell if your system is using it when in standby because all of the fans and such do not shut off.  If the system generally appears to have turned off when you suspend, then it's S3.

Comment: I have a S1/S3 option in my BIOS config. It appears to be a fairly common option (thank you Google). On the other hand, references to the actual use of S2 are rather rare...

Comment: @Bob, oops, you're right, I got S1 and S2 mixed up.  Fixed.