# Enable Wake on LAN on Asus motherboard

Tags: bios, wake-on-lan

I would like to enable Wake on LAN on my Asus A88X-gaming PC. It receives the WOL packets, but my PC doesn't power on.  Must I change some BIOS settings?

[image: Print screen: WOL packets on Wireshark]

[image: A88XM BIOS APM picture]

Comment: "Have I to change some settings on my Bios?" - Yes, you have to activate WOL in the BIOS.

Comment: Hello, if you watch picture two you can see that I have already activate the WAL option.

Comment: My only guess now is that you must enable the "Deep S4" sleep mode for WOL to function (which is now disabled). See [here](https://superuser.com/a/71843/427002).

Answer (score 0):

Try to find "Network Stack" in BIOS and enable that. That enable me to WOL from shot down status with a Z390 board. Windows Fast startup must be disabled to wake up from shut down status.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked for me is shown in the picture. Try to find in BIOS something like [Power On by PCI-E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEdTF.jpg)