# Ubuntu 20.04 Battery drains even after the laptop is shut down after changing from Windows

Tags: ubuntu, battery, shutdown, thinkpad

I recently switched from windows to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Lenovo e560. Whenever I press shutdown, everything shuts and the screen goes black. Pressing neither of keys other than a power key wakes it up. However battery drains overnight and sometimes its dead.

The unusual behavior I noticed is whenever my PC shuts, the red indicator used to blink three times before but now it blinks for a single time. I tried a hard shutdown by long pressing the power button for the confirmation and it shutdowns with 3 blinks as usual.

I believe the shutdown is not happening properly. Also, the performance of battery is fine and its a giving a good backup when I am working.
Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I read someone fixed a similar issue by updating their graphics drivers and switching the display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. (More info on display managers here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them )

Comment: Are you still having this problem Sailesh ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it may not be turning off and suspect it's going into suspend mode.

You should check

```
sudo cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf| grep HandleLidSwitch
```

It can be assigned to

1. poweroff
2. hibernate
3. ignore
4. suspend

To what value is yours assigned? Edit the file if necessary.

If it's correct, can you try the poweroff command from terminal instead?

```
sudo poweroff -f
```

Comment: Hi Joshua I tried your suggestion and changed HandleLidSwitch to poweroff from. I also tried sudo poweroff -f . It shuts down my pc with one blink however battery is still draining. I then shut it down by long pressing power button until the indicator blinks three times on next day, the battery didn't drain even a single percent

Answer (score 0):

Happened to my HP Pavilion 15 after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. Disabling Network Boot in BIOS seems to have solved the problem. If your device have Wake-on-LAN, please also disable that.
It took me a while to identify the problem in the first place. The battery was draining to 0% and laptop was getting quite warm inside my travel bag.

This is a very serious issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not a problem with your OS or shutdown sequence. Go to your BIOS settings and turn OFF ""Always ON USB" and "wake up on LAN".
I have noticed that Power drain during shutdown was happening in windows 10 as well (5 to 6% in 8 hours) but I found it much pronounced over Ubuntu. (100% in 7 hours).
I hope it addresses the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have a new Lenovo Thinkpad E15 dual-boot Win 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

I'd created a custom keyboard shortcut that ran `systemctl suspend` (https://askubuntu.com/a/1795/48214), which I triggered on Fri and then let my computer sit unplugged all weekend.  Then when I opened the screen on Monday, it wouldn't boot unless plugged in. And of course then I saw the battery was at 0%.

https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/draining-battery.html told me to run `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`, which resulted in `[deep]`, which is what I wanted.

From what I've read elsewhere, what I think I'll do going forward instead is run `systemctl hibernate`. My guess is that hibernation is a better way to save the battery all weekend long.

Comment: Suspend and deep (what I believe is actually "standby") are both states that will continue to deplete battery because the RAM is powered. hibernate saves the system state to disk and turns the RAM off. hibernate will also consume power for AoL and WoL, so it is not the better way. off should be most conservative. the OP is attempting to shutdown, which is off. 

Here's more details: https://superuser.com/a/71843/6044